# Repeatibility issue with win32com.client

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, win32com

I have written a bit of code to automate some work, this includes extracting Excel attachments from a particular Outlook folder, storing it at location (with date-time in file name) and then extracting some data from it.

I have a fully functional code using Jupyter notebook. However, when I create an .exe (using auto-py-to-exe) and run I get an error on a specific method SentOn. Any pointers on what can be the cause?

I tried to use restrict but did not work if I do not enter date, time explicitly. I would like to use the parameter auto-defined.

Does not work:

```py
lastWk_dt = dt.timedelta(days=-7) + currentWk
lastWk = lastWk_dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") ## convert to str and format
messages = calloutFolder.Items.restrict(f"[SentOn] > {lastWk}")
```

Does work but not useful:

```py
messages = calloutFolder.Items.restrict("[SentOn] > '08/13/2019 06:00 AM'")
```

```py
import os
import shutil
import win32com.client
import datetime as dt

## defining timeline of data extraction
currentWk = dt.datetime.now().date()
lastWk = dt.timedelta(days=-7) + currentWk

## creating folders for storing attachments
cwd = os.getcwd()
savePath = cwd +"/"+str(currentWk)

try:
    shutil.rmtree(savePath)
    os.mkdir(savePath)
except OSError as e:
    os.mkdir(savePath)

## reading MS Outlook subfolder called "SOME FOLDER" in inbox
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
calloutFolder = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["SOME FOLDER"]
messages = calloutFolder.Items

for message in messages:
    if (message.Senton.date() <= currentWk) and (message.Senton.date() >= lastWk):  
            # source of bug, wherever I place SentOn it bugs out
            attachment = message.Attachments.Item(1)

            # changes message to read
            message.Unread = False 

            ## saving attachments
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(savePath, str(attachment)))
                break
```

Expected result would be various Excel files renamed and saved in location "savePath"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastWk` is datetime.datetime object. try

`messages = calloutFolder.Items.restrict(f"[SentOn] > '{lastWk}'")`

that is using f-strings (available in 3.6+). otherwise use `str.format()` method.

You may need to explicitly convert `lastWk` to specific format. In this case look at `datetime.datetime.strftime()`

Comment: I did convert and reformat lastWk to string. Updated code to show. Did not work. Tried using f-string literal and .format() but bugs out at that line

Comment: comparing to the one that works, but not useful the only difference is missing single quotes around the date, i.e. `messages = calloutFolder.Items.restrict(f"[SentOn] > '{lastWk}'")`

Comment: That worked! I was able to run the code to completion and achieve the result. Thank you!